# No steam connection, doesn't select default character

Tags: borderlands-2

I just restarted Borderlands 2, it was working fine a minute ago. When I restarted it, the first thing I noticed was it didn't select my default character, but instead it selected a level 1 Axton as the default character.

Then I noticed no one was online, which is wrong, there's always someone online. I checked the Network settings and LAN was selected, so I tried selecting another option to get me online, but I can't select anything except LAN and Offline.

And when I try to look at DLC it says I need a connection to Steam to do that, except I am connected to Steam.

This actually isn't the first time I've had this problem, I had it on another computer a while ago and I know I fixed it but I don't remember how. I already tried verifying game integrity.

Comment: Is your steam online? Might be a server down. Did you restart Steam?

Comment: Yes, Steam was online, it's definitely an issue with the game. Every other game but this one works perfectly.

Comment: The problem seems to be linked to my controller and that feels right because I think that's the same thing that caused it last time. I use a PS3 controller emulated as a 360 controller using Motioninjoy.